# Inspecting the JSON response before sending the response in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I need to inspect the JSON response before sending it out via the controller. The Serializer attaches some fields to the response that I need to inspect which will determine if I fire an event in a separate thread/send an email. How do I inspect the JSON response before sending it out via the controller?

Here's what I have in my Rails controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.any(*Version.formats) do
    render json: stuffs, each_serializer: StuffsSerializer
  end
end
```

The above just renders json and sends it immediately whereas I need an intermediate step to just inspect `stuffs` after it has been serialized. I prefer to do this in a line above the respond_to block. How can I do this?

Comment: Before you follow that path, make sure you are aware that this isn't a good practice. There is no good reason for that "conditional" to be stored on the serializer.

Comment: as i understand u just want to inspect yr stuffs `render plain: stuffs`

Comment: It wouldn't be on the serializer. It's on the controller. The serializer has a method that dynamically returns different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
stuffs_json = ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(stuffs, each_serializer: StuffsSerializer)
```

Then you can inspect this variable and just put it inside **render**